# SQL Database Update in C++ QT Not Advancing to Next ID

Tags: c++, sql, qt

```
QSqlQuery query(db);

for (int i = 0; i < graph.GetTotalV(); i++) {
    query.prepare("UPDATE stadiums SET teamName=:name, stadiumName=:stad, capacity=:cap, "
                  "location=:loc, conference=:con, surfaceType=:sur, roofType=:roof, starName=:star WHERE stadiumID = :id");
    query.bindValue(":name", "name");
    query.bindValue(":stad", "stad");
    query.bindValue(":cap", 123);
    query.bindValue(":loc", "loc");
    query.bindValue(":con", "con");
    query.bindValue(":sur", "sur");
    query.bindValue(":roof", "roof");
    query.bindValue(":star", "star");
    query.bindValue(":id", i);
    query.exec();
}
```

This is my code that involves a loop to update all values in my database to, as of right now, these new values. However, when I run the code, only the values that are aligned with stadiumID = 0 are updated. When I manually change the last line to "WHERE stadiumID = 1", it does nothing instead, as if there was no other rows beyond index 0. What could be causing this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: You should probably add some of QT tag, to get that crowd to see the question.

Comment: Did you check how many times the loop lopped ? Might be that your graph.GetTotalV()  doesn't return a value > 0

Answer (score 0):

I don't think.., but try to remove spaces. 
stadiumID = :id
to
stadiumID=:id

Comment: can you post the filled fields of the database?

Comment: http://imgur.com/5Yzpi7H . The graph.GetTotalV method equals 32 in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. In SQLite, I forgot to uncheck "make unique" for the team name and star player values. That was why it simply disregarded them when I tried to insert the same values.